# It is too laggy for dragging pictures from web browser to pantheon-files

Tags: pantheon-files, plank

https://youtu.be/uxr5K9nrCCU

Sometimes I need to download some images, it is more convient for me by dragging the images to pantheon-files, but the animation is too slow.

Comment: Do you know what version of elementary OS you are using? It doesn't look or behave like my copy of Freya 0.3.1

Comment: 0.3.2 with Arc theme

Comment: Okay, so I can reproduce this (albeit a little faster) in Firefox and even Midori. Chrome just doesn't even have this drag-and-drop support.